# Sentry server not responding on Celery logs

Tags: django, celery, sentry, raven

I have a problem related with sending log messages to Sentry server while using Django and Celery async tasks. I utilize Django 1.11, Raven 6.1, Celery 4.0.2.

The log message shows in Sentry server when task is launching synchronous, for example:

```
@celery.shared_task()
def test_worker():
    logger.warning('Logger works!')
    raise Exception('---Worker works!')

$ from api.tasks import test_worker
$ test_worker()
```

When trying launch async task using:
    $ res = test_worker.delay()
Sentry server does not contain log about logger.

My settings.py is:

```
RAVEN_CONFIG = {
    'dsn': 'http://my_dsn',
}

SENTRY_AUTO_LOG_STACKS = True

LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': True,
    'root': {
        'level': 'DEBUG',
        'handlers': ['sentry'],
    },
    'formatters': {
        'standard': {
            'format': '%(asctime)s [%(levelname)s] %(name)s - %(message)s'
        },
    'verbose': {
        'format': '%(asctime)s [%(levelname)s] %(module)s:%(funcName)s -  %(message)s'
        },
    },
    'handlers': {
        # logs directly to Sentry
        'sentry': {
             'level': 'DEBUG',
             'class': 'raven.contrib.django.raven_compat.handlers.SentryHandler',
        },
        # logs everything to the console
        'console': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
            'formatter': 'verbose',
        },
    },
    'loggers': {
        'raven': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'handlers': ['console'],
            'propagate': False,
        },
        'sentry.errors': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'handlers': ['console'],
            'propagate': False,
        },
        'processing': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'handlers': ['sentry'],
            'propagate': False
        },
        'celery': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'handlers': ['sentry'],
            'propagate': False
        }
    },
}
```

Where I made a mistake, or what I am doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.